# forEach change color text in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

I'm trying to solve an exercise in vanilla JS but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I would like to change to color text to red if the product price is > 300.

In the console.log I'm getting all ok but on `changeColor.style.color = "red";` I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

Also because the page has a lazy load I could I get all price change by the time you are scrolling down?

Thanks

```
function exercise_3() {
  var offer = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price");
  var price = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price");
  let changePriceColor = 300;

  price.forEach( (price) => {
    var changeColor = price.innerHTML.slice(0,4).replace(/,/g, '');
    if (changeColor > changePriceColor) {
      console.log(changeColor, "true");
    } else {
      console.log(changeColor, "false")
    }
  })
}

exercise_3();
```

Comment: `var changeColor = price.innerHTML.slice(0,4).replace(/,/g, '');` - changeColor isnt an element?

Comment: Oh yes, it is. if I'm console.log I'm getting what I need

Comment: I mean... it's not... your fix listed below is because you're using `price` - not `changeColor`

Comment: it is working now but only on the content loaded on the page. because of lazy load, I can't make it works when scrolling down because not rendered yet. I could I do that?

Comment: Once the content loads you have to re-call your function.

Comment: that is where I'm strugglingon how to recall the function

Comment: You can update the question  with the code that does the lazy loading.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because it is an exercise on DOM manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends...
One way is to create an array to store all the elements that are loaded and compare to that array.
Another way to do it is to count the difference between the amout of elements in the DOM compared to the elements you have done.

Perhaps something like this:

```
var numberOfPriceElements = 0;

// count elements on load
numberOfPriceElements = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price").length;

document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    // if count of elements is more then do the function and save the amount to the variable. 
    if(document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price").length > numberOfPriceElements) {
        exercise_3();
        numberOfPriceElements = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price").length;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `changeColor` is an result of your regex for the innerHTML, not an element.
variable `price` is your element where you can change the color.
So try `price.style.color="red"`

Answer (score 1):

To run the function `exercise_3` when scrolling you have to add an event listener for scrolling.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
   exercise_3();
});
```

But that will run the function every time you scroll and will be bad for performence.

Comment: How could I tackle that?

Comment: To long for comments.. please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your lazy loading issue, we can us scroll event listener and **scrollY** property of **window** as,

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
   var scroll_position = window.scrollY;
   if(scroll_position > 250){
      element.style.backgroundColor = '#29323c';
   }
})
```

In above code change **scroll_position** comparison value according to your need(I have taken 250 as a dummy value)

**window.scrollY:** It is property which return  the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically.

**Note: also don't add your updated solution as answers to your own question you could just update your question**

Answer (score 0):

```
    var offer = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price");
    var price = document.querySelectorAll(".grocery-item__normal-price");
    let changePriceColor = 300;


    price.forEach( (price) => {
    var changeColor = price.innerHTML.slice(0,4).replace(/,/g, '');
    if( changeColor > changePriceColor ) {
        price.style.color = "red";
       console.log(price, "true");
    } else {
        console.log(changeColor, "false")
        }
    })
}

exercise_3();
```

This is actually fixed the color issue, but can't understand how to make it works on scroll down due to lazy load